# Using bluecove to receive messages from phone

Tags: bluetooth, inputstream, bluecove

I am trying to implement a server type specification on my pc that receives messages from my phone and then does stuff with them. I may have the entirely wrong end of the stick here, but I am using bluecove and have this on my pc:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
    //display local device address and name
    LocalDevice localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
    System.out.println("Address: "+localDevice.getBluetoothAddress());
    System.out.println("Name: "+localDevice.getFriendlyName());
    System.out.println("Discoverable: "+localDevice.getDiscoverable());

    DiscoveryAgent agent = localDevice.getDiscoveryAgent();
    RemoteDevice remoteDeviceArray[] = agent.retrieveDevices(0);
    System.out.println("array: " + Arrays.toString(remoteDeviceArray));

    SelectServiceHandler handler = new SelectServiceHandler(agent);
    for (int i=0; i<remoteDeviceArray.length; i++)
    {
        RemoteDevice remoteDevice = (RemoteDevice)remoteDeviceArray[i];
        String address = remoteDevice.getBluetoothAddress();
        System.out.println("remoteAddress: " + address);
        if (address.equals(myAddress))
        {
            UUID[] uuidSet = new UUID[1];
            uuidSet[0] = new UUID(0x1105); //OBEX Object Push service
            int[] attrSet = new int[] {0x0100}; //Service name
            agent.searchServices(attrSet, uuidSet, remoteDevice, handler);
            System.out.println("successfully found phone");
            String service = agent.selectService(uuidSet[0], ServiceRecord.NOAUTHENTICATE_NOENCRYPT, false);
            Server server = new Server();
            server.startServer(service);
        }
    }
}

private void startServer(String service) throws IOException{  
    DataInputStream inputStream = Connector.openDataInputStream(service);
}
```

The pc, on boot, looks through the devices it has already paired with. If one of them has "myAddress" (which I specified somewhere else - the id of my phone), it searches the phone's services, and tries to find the OBEX Object Push Service (which I have seen from various guides is what I want to be looking for here).
I then try and open an input stream for this service, to receive messages. 
Currently, I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.intel.bluetooth.obex.OBEXClientSessionImpl cannot be cast to javax.microedition.io.InputConnection
    at com.intel.bluetooth.MicroeditionConnector.openInputStream(MicroeditionConnector.java:565)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.MicroeditionConnector.openDataInputStream(MicroeditionConnector.java:545)
    at javax.microedition.io.Connector.openDataInputStream(Connector.java:127)
    at Server.startServer(Server.java:24)
    at Server.main(Server.java:80)
```

Which I understand from other posts might be because I am trying to cast a client service connection to a server inputstream, but I don't think that's what I am doing here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am really struggling with the whole concept of bluecove.

Cheers.

Comment: Did you get  ```BlueCove stack shutdown completed```

Comment: @AyushBansal sorry for the late reply, yes I do get that after the error.